# Javalin hot reload of static files

Tags: javalin

I configured a static folder to be served by Javalin:

```
Javalin.create {
   it.addStaticFiles("/public")
}
```

In Javalin logs I see:

```
[main] INFO io.javalin.Javalin - Static file handler added:
{urlPathPrefix: "/", path: "/public", location: Location.CLASSPATH}
Resolved path: 'file:///Users/ls/projects/store/build/resources/main/public/'
[main] INFO io.javalin.Javalin -
```

Which is fine. Files get served.
But every time I change a JS/HTML/CSS file, I need to restart Javalin.
Is there any way around this? I just wanted to refresh the browser for the sake of quick development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an external location (i.e not a "classpath" location) for your static files:

```
config.addStaticFiles("/path/to/external/folder", Location.EXTERNAL);
```

In that case, changes will be picked up without needing a Javalin restart.